# jQuery Deferred: Rejecting a Promise from within a Done Filter

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

Fyi, I'm just starting to learn jQuery promises, so I may be a bit confused here.

Anyway, I have an AJAX request that I want to reject from within a done filter based on the content of the response:

```
return doAJAXRequest().then(function (data) {
    if (data.responseText == "YES") {
        return doOtherAJAXRequest();
    } else {
        this.reject(data);
    }
});
```

That didn't work as I expected:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'reject'
```

How do I make this promise fail based on its response? Is that possible? Or am I just confused about what needs to be done here?

Comment: Try changing this.reject to $(this).reject.

Comment: @rtimoshenko Are you sure that's right?

Comment: @rtimoshenko That doesn't seem to be working, I'm still getting the same error. Edit: Actually it's not exactly the same, but still very similar. (`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'reject'`)

Comment: My mistake, I saw "this" and made an assumption. Have you compared your code with the documentation? http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/ You might try using the global $.Deferred().reject. Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pgBCD/

Comment: @rtimoshenko Well, this seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/pgBCD/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Throwing an Error in jQuery's Deferred object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843297/throwing-an-error-in-jquerys-deferred-object)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In jQuery (unlike some other libs), transmogrifying a promise from a 'resolved' state to an 'rejected' state is slightly verbose, requiring the explicit creation and rejection of a new Deferred.

```
function foo() {
    return doAJAXRequest().then(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if (data.responseText == "YES") {
            return doOtherAJAXRequest(data);
        } else {
            return $.Deferred().reject(jqXHR, data, 'Not YES').promise();
        }
    });
)
```

Here, the promise returned if `data.responseText !== "YES"` mimics (in part) a failed ajax request, while still allowing `data` to be passed. This is (probably) important for the downstream `.fail()` handler, which must handle both genuine ajax failures AND transmogrified success conditions, without knowing which one occurred until it reads `errorThrown`.

```
foo().fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    if(errorThrown == 'Not YES') {
        //transmogrified success
        var data = textStatus;
        ...
    }
    else {
        //genuine ajax failure
        ...
    }
});
```

It is generally easier to pass `data` in this way rather than re-obtaining it from the jqXHR object. This is particularly true with JSON encoded data, which would otherwise need to be decoded a second time in the fail handler.

Comment: I don't think the promise() part is needed (or not anymore), which makes the call a bit less ugly/longish.