# How to reject a promise from inside then function

Tags: javascript, promise

This is probably a silly question, but mid promise chain, how do you reject a promise from inside one of the then functions?  For example:

```
someActionThatReturnsAPromise()
    .then(function(resource) {
        return modifyResource(resource)
    })
    .then(function(modifiedResource) {
        if (!isValid(modifiedResource)) {
            var validationError = getValidationError(modifiedResource);
            // fail promise with validationError
        }
    })
    .catch(function() {
        // oh noes
    });
```

There's no longer a reference to the original resolve/reject function or the PromiseResolver.  Am I just supposed to add `return Promise.reject(validationError);` ?

Comment: `throw validationError`

Comment: ><  I had a feeling it would be something silly/easy that.  Guess I kept thinking that I had to call a dedicated rejection function or return a failed Promise instead.  So from inside a promise/thenable, any returned value that is not a new Promise will be considered the resolved value?  And if I throw an error, that's the same as returning an immediately rejected Promise?  If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: You are probably looking for the accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800176/jquery-deferred-rejecting-a-promise-from-within-a-done-filter

Answer (score 107, accepted):

> Am I just supposed to add `return Promise.reject(validationError);`?

Yes. However, [it's that complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843297/throwing-an-error-in-jquerys-deferred-object) only in jQuery, with a [Promise/A+](http://promisesaplus.com/)-compliant library you also could simply

```
throw validationError;
```

So your code would then look like

```
someActionThatReturnsAPromise()
    .then(modifyResource)
    .then(function(modifiedResource) {
        if (!isValid(modifiedResource))
            throw getValidationError(modifiedResource);
        // else !
        return modifiedResource;
    })
    .catch(function() {
        // oh noes
    });
```

Comment: Is this a regular thing to do? Is it widely used? I feel bad doing it, because if somewhere in the code `.catch` is missing, the **whole** app will blow up with unhalted error..

Comment: Note that in a Promise/A+ compliant library you can use throw because the `handler` for `then` is sync and the exception can be catched. If the handler is async, it has to return a promise to eventually reject. So always returning Promise.reject() instead of throwing makes sense to me. Because if you throw in an async handler, the library can't catch it and it will silently pass. Beware.

Comment: @MikeGleasonjrCouturier: There should be no async handlers that are not `.then` handlers on a promise :-) If you're using a not promisified API, then even `return Promise.reject()` will help you.

Comment: @Bergi I meant like: `p.then(function() { doAsync(function() { throw new Error("won't catch"); }); });`  EDIT: oh okay I re-read your comment, I'm totally with you, we are on the same page! I wanted to point it out to the OP :)

Comment: @MikeGleasonjrCouturier: Yes, that's exactly what I was saying. And `doAsync(function() { return Promise.reject(new Error("won't catch, won't throw")); })` doesn't work there either - it just fails silently. It really should be `doAsync().then(function() { throw new Error("will be caught"); })` when you're working with promises.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Promise.reject`

Like this

```
function test()
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(null)
    }).then(() => console.info('yes')).then(() => {
        return Promise.reject('hek');
    })
}

test().then(() => console.info('resolved')).catch(() => console.info('rejected'))
```