# Reject a promise from then()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

How can you reject a promise from inside its `then()`?

For example:

```
Promise.all(promiseArr).then(()=>{
  if(cond){
    //reject
  }
}).catch(()=>{ /*do something*/ });
```

The only relevant question I found was this: 
[How to reject a promise from inside then function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21260602/how-to-reject-a-promise-from-inside-then-function) but it's from 2014, so there must be a better way then to throw by now with support of ES6.

Comment: A rejected promise is just the async way to describe an Error

Comment: Does it matter what I throw? @Thomas

Comment: ideally, something that describes the error that happened any you'll want to show in your console if unhandled.

Comment: `throw`ing is still perfectly valid in ES6. You could also `return Promise.reject()` if `throw` feels unnatural.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ES6/ES2015 is still JavaScript and doesn't offer anything new regarding promise rejection. In fact, native promises *are* ES6.

It is either

```
promise
.then(() => {
  return Promise.reject(...);
})
.catch(...);
```

or

```
promise
.then(() => {
  throw ...;
})
.catch(...);
```

And `throw` is more idiomatic (and generally more performant) way to do this.

This may not be true for other promise implementations. E.g. in AngularJS `throw` and `$q.reject()` is not the same thing.

Comment: "E.g. in AngularJS throw and $q.reject() is not the same thing.": can you elaborate on this or provide a link to a more detailed information? I can't find anything regarding those differences.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is described in AngularJS docs, but `throw` inside `catch` or `then` results in uncaught error, while `return $q.reject()` results in rejected promise.

Answer (score 2):

I have found out (after hours of scratching my head) that if a `throw` is within an async method such as `setTimeout(() => throw new Error('description'))` it will be treated as an `Unhandled Exception` and will NOT end up in your `.catch()` block (you'll only see it in the console window) - see [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) where I found out about that difference between `throw` and `Promise.reject`.