# reject deferred inside jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I'm using $.ajax to get some HTML from the server.

my javascript makes use of promises and I want to avoid creating another promise and use jQuery ajax since it's already a promise.

But is there some way I can reject the promise inside the "done" callback?

my code looks something like this:

```
function get_html(){

   return $.ajax({ .... }).done(function(response){

     if(response.haveErrors){
       // here how do I reject and return the promise?
       return;
     }

     // code #2 should run normally
     // but can i pass a "parameter" to done() ?

   }).fail(function(){
      ....
   });
}
```

and the usage:

```
get_html().done(function(parameter){
      // code #2
    }).fail(function(){

});
```

Also, is it possible to pass a parameter to code # 2? in the done callback?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Deferred: Rejecting a Promise from within a Done Filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800176/jquery-deferred-rejecting-a-promise-from-within-a-done-filter)

Answer (score 5):

> Is there some way I can reject the promise inside the "done" callback?

No, because `done` does not create a new promise, and is only called when the promise is already fulfilled. You need to use [`then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) for chaining - it creates a new promise that can be rejected from the callback. However, with jQuery [this is a bit more complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10843297/1048572), we cannot just `throw` in the callback.

So use

```
function get_html() {
    return $.ajax({…}).then(function(response) {
        if (response.hasErrors) {
            return $.Deferred().reject(response.errors);
        }
        // else
        return response; // which is getting passed as the parameter below
    });
}
```

and then

```
get_html().then(function(parameter) {
  // code #2
}, function(err) {
  // …
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your code should be like below:

```
function get_html(){
    return $.ajax({ .... });
}

get_html().done(function(response){
    // process a response from your server here...
}).fail(function(){
    // process errors here...
});
```

Comment: I dont want to process the response from my server there. That get_html function is supposed to be used in multiple places. I don't want to copy the code in every place :(