# How to trigger "fail" handlers on an Ajax Promise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I force a successful response from `$.ajax` to fire its "fail" handlers from within a "done" handler?

The [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) says the `jqXHR` object implements the Promise interface, which means it has no `reject` method.

Below shows some code listening for failures on a `jqXHR` object created inside another scope.

If the successful response is actually a well-formed error, I want to trigger handlers that are listening for "fail".

```js
// common function
function doAjax(options) {
  return $.ajax(options).fail(function() {
    // common error handling
  }.done(function(result, status, xhr) {
    if (result.isBAD) {
      xhr.reject(); // <- not a jqXHR method
    }
  }));
}

// listening elsewhere
doAjax(options).fail(function() {
  // specific error handling
});
```

Comment: I don't believe you can. Given that `done`/`fail` is intended to work on the state of the request, not its content, the logic you're trying to create goes against that principle.

Comment: Perhaps the doAjax function could return a custom Deferred object instead?

Comment: I guess that would mean client code not having access to the original XMLHttpRequest, but I might be able to live with that

Comment: Yes, you could return your own promise/deferred that you choose the cases that get resolved/rejected.

Comment: Possible same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800176/jquery-deferred-rejecting-a-promise-from-within-a-done-filter

Comment: thanks @freedomn-m I did look for existing Qs, but failed to find that one.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by returning my own promise instead of the jqXHR instance. It means that client code doesn't have access to other ajax details, but in my case this isn't a problem.

```js
function doAjax(options) {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  return $.ajax(options)
    .fail( function() {
      deferred.reject();
    })
    .done( function(result,status,xhr) {
      if( result.isBAD ){
        deferred.reject();
      }else {
        deferred.resolve();
      }
    })
  ;
  return deferred.promise();
}
```