# Can I force jQuery Deferred/Ajax to execute fail handler after it has been resolved?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

An example to make clear what i want to do. This is what I would usually do:

```
function success(data, status, jqxhr){
  if ( data.error )
    return failure(jqxhr, status, data.error);
  // process data
}
function failure(jqxhr, status, err){
  ...
}

$.ajax( ... )
  .done(success)
  .fail(failure)
```

Is there any way, i can accomplish this with anonymous functions only, like so?

```
   $.ajax( ... )
      .done(function(data, status, jqxhr){
         if(data.error)
            // what do i need to do here to jump in to the fail handler?
      })
      .fail(function(jqxhr, status, err){
         ...
      })
```

Comment: a Deferred object's state can be set only once....

Comment: I know that. Is there still any way to force the execution of failure handlers?

Comment: technically you can use a goto. But in practice it's better not to do it

Comment: What about using `.always()`?

Comment: @NabilKadimi, then i would need an additional check, whether always was called after a success or failure, but it's an idea

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan: Are you serious? Also, would one use `goto` in JavaScript?

Comment: @Bergi what you can technically do is not what you actually would do. I thought I were clear. It's a solution but not necessarily a good solution (I would never use) - that's the reason I wrote a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan: Sure, but I'd be really interested in how it is technically possible to use `goto` in JavaScript. I've never heard of that?

Comment: ... @Bergi I must had dead hamsters in my mind when I thought about a goto approach when I was actually thinking about labelled statement. (*Ok, it's all fine. Breath!*)

Comment: @Fabrizio: Ah, right, I love these :-) Unfortunately they don't work across function boundaries.

Comment: @Bergi, I know, I'm just getting older :D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> what do i need to do here to jump in to the fail handler?

Don't use `done`, but `then` to map over the result of the promise. By [returning a rejected promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843297/throwing-an-error-in-jquerys-deferred-object) you can "throw" an error and reject the resulting promise, so that your fail handler is executed.

```
$.ajax(…)
  .then(function(data, status, jqxhr){
    if (data.error)
      return $.Deferred().reject(data.error);
    else
      return data; // if you want to return multiple arguments, you'd use
                   // $.Deferred().resolve(data, status, jqxhr);
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    …
  })
  .fail(function(jqxhr, status, err){
    …
  });
```

Comment: i knew, it had to be possible! thanks. i've came across the `then` handler, but never quite understood its purpose.

Comment: But when we return new `$.Deferred()` object, we loose access to `.abort()` method `jqXHR` has? `$.Deferred()` object doesn't have it.

Comment: @manakor: You always loose that when you use `then`, this doesn't have anything to do with the callback return value. if you need `abort`, store a reference to the `jqXHR` object before chaining promise callbacks to it.