# How to make a request which returns a fake response in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, response

Within my code I want to catch some POST request errors. To test this, I want to fake the response of the POST request. Is there a way I can do this in JavaScript?

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    // further arguments
}).done(function (result) {
    // Sunny day
}).fail(function(result) {
    // Catch it!
});
```

I want a statuscode to be returned other than 200 as a response

Comment: I want a statuscode returned as a response other than 200 . It is within my Javascript code. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentary page of jQuery ([Source](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/));

> jqXHR.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});
>
> An alternative construct to the error callback option, the .fail() method replaces the deprecated .error() method. Refer to deferred.fail() for implementation details.

so if you end your response of your `url` with a http code other than `200` will end in '.fail'.

For example if you add a header to your php file like below it should work.

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```

An alternative method to the header() function is http_response_code() you may check that link [http_response_code()](https://secure.php.net/manual/tr/function.http-response-code.php)

Hope this helps

Comment: I am trying to add the request header, but I am getting the following response: "SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 'HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found' is not a valid HTTP header field name." Instead I rather get a 404 Not Found sothat I can catch this. Should I convert this into a 'header' and 'value' instead of adding the string completely?

Comment: Actually you do not need to use `setRequestHeader` why u try to do this? Since you try to check `.done` or `.fail` callbacks we have a simple rule separation of these 2 callbacks. If your resource responses with 200 code which means OK in http messaging will be handled in `.done` all others will be handled in `.fail`. So if you 'fake' your response with the code other than 200 your `.fail` jQuery callback will fire. Conclusion: you should make header modifiction in your php file, not in javascript code.

Comment: Also i have updated my answer with alternative method for header(); you may check the changes.

Comment: That's stupid of me... The question is related to my javascript file. I'm sorry for the confusion. But still. I tried to make a header modification within `setRequestHeader`. Should I do this somewhere else? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. So you may try the answer in that question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110775/can-i-force-jquery-deferred-ajax-to-execute-fail-handler-after-it-has-been-resol

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way could be to use just call an url that actually returns that code like so:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://httpstat.us/400',
    type: 'POST',
    // further arguments
}).done(function (result) {
    console.log("Success");
}).fail(function(result) {
    console.log("Fail");
    console.log("Result", result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

But you can also, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29680013/479156), override the `$.ajax()` function to always fail like so:

```js
function ajax_fail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    return function (params) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred().reject(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
        return deferred.promise();
    }
}

$.ajax = ajax_fail();

$.ajax({
    url: '',
    type: 'POST'
}).done(function (result) {
    console.log("Success");
}).fail(function (result) {
    console.log("Error");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The parameters you pass to the `ajax_fail()` function will be the ones your `.fail()` callback will add. You can add there whatever you like to be returned.

Small warning: Don't use this in production or if you still want other `$.ajax` calls to work. Every time you call `$.ajax()` it will fail this way.

If you want to only do this for one AJAX call, do something like this:

```
var ajaxFunc = $.ajax;
// use the above code

// restore old $.ajax function
$.ajax = ajaxFunc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to use [fiddler autoResponder](https://www.telerik.com/videos/fiddler/using-fiddler-s-auto-responder-feature) than js. You can catch response with 200 code, edit the response and test your error handling.