# Break jQuery Ajax then / promise sequence

Tags: jquery, promise

I have a sequence of jQuery promises that I get from ajax calls. For example:

```
 AjaxCall1.then(AjaxCall2).then(AjaxCall3) etc...
```

Between some of the ajax calls I do some processing, for example the first one gets what to search for, the next one performs the search, the third one processes the results from the search.

What I want to do is break the seqeuence if AjaxCall2 does not return a search result. (and I will actually re-run the function)

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

With then you can pass a second param as your failed callback function

```
AjaxCall1.then( AjaxCall2, AjaxCall1 ).then(AjaxCall3, AjaxCall2)
```

or use .done and .fail

```
AjaxCall1.done( AjaxCall2 ).fail( AjaxCall1 ).... //and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to do is break the seqeuence if AjaxCall2 does not return a search result.

Just don't "return no result", but "throw an exception" - and the sequence will automatically break. You can do so by [rejecting a deferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843297/throwing-an-error-in-jquerys-deferred-object) in your `AjaxCall2` function.

> and I will actually re-run the function

You might even re-run them by installing them as an error handler:

```
function tryToFind() {
    return AjaxCall1().then(AjaxCall2); // which might fail
}
tryToFind().then(null, tryToFind /* again! */).then(AjaxCall3);
```