# jQuery: Adding "callback" Parameter for JSONP Doesn't Trigger Callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp, promise

The following piece of code, which calls a service using jQuery's getJSON, without the `useJsonp` section, worked fine for me for a long time. Then, there was a need to support JSONP and the `if (useJsonp)` condition was added. This also works fine, until the HTTP request fails. When I'm failing it (using Fiddler) with an 404 response, none of the callback (`.done` nor `.fail` is being called). When the request doesn't fail, I get to the `.done` callback.

```
function getData(url){
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    if (useJsonp) {
        url += '&callback=?';
    }
    $.when($.getJSON(url))
        .done(function (dataObj) {
            if (!dataObj || dataObj.Status === 'failed') {
                dfd.reject(dataObj);
            }
            else {
                doSomething(dataObj);
                dfd.resolve(dataObj);
            }
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR) {
            dfd.reject(jqXHR);
        });
    return dfd.promise();
};
```

Why is that? What can I do to make the callbacks called?

Thanks

Comment: WTH are you doing there? `$.getJSON` does already return a promise, `$.when()` does already return a promise, there is absolutely no reason to use `$.Deferred()`. Just `return $.getJSON(useJsonp?url+'&callback=?':url)` is enough.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi - I edited the code to demonstrate that even if the getJSON was successful, I might need to reject it. So I can just call `return $.getJSON(...)`, I need to do something and then return the promise. This entire code is called somewhat like this: `$.when(getData(url)).done(...).fail(...)`.

Comment: OK, still you should use [`then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) (like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10843297/1048572)), instead of [manually constructing deferreds](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#wiki-the-deferred-anti-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

$.when closing bracket is mising, is it because of that, please try,other code is by far correct. This it the way it is to be achieved.

```
var dfd = $.Deferred();
if (useJsonp) {
    url += '&callback=?';
}
$.when($.getJSON(url))
    .done(function (dataObj) {
        dfd.resolve(dataObj);
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR) {
        dfd.reject(jqXHR);
    }));
return dfd.promise();
```

Comment: No closing bracket is missing there. The done & fail callbacks are chained.

Answer (score 0):

For jsonp requests I do the following:

```
$.ajax(url, {
    dataType: useJsonp ? "jsonp" : undefined,
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        alert("It worked!");
    },
    error: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        alert("It didn't work!");
    }
});
```