# Chain jquery promises, but handle failures separately

Tags: jquery, promise

The scenario is as following:

- a call is made to the server that returns an array of objects if
  everything is fine.
- if an error occurs on the server, it returns a
  json that contains an error message.

Out of this scenario, I want to create a function that returns a promise, which I can use like this from a client:

```
initData()
    .done(function(myArray) {
        processData(myArray);
    })
    .fail(function(response) {
        console.log("An error occured: " + response.errorMessage);
    });
```

The client should not care that initData() makes a call to a server, it should get the fail() called for both ajax call failures or server specific errors.

For this I need two things:

1. Hide the failure of the server call and create a new error message object.
2. Make the promise fail if the call to the server returned with an error message object.

Here's what I have:

```
function initData() {
    var promise = $.getJSON(url);

    return promise.then(function(response) {
        if (typeof response !== 'undefined' && response !== null && typeof response.errorMessage !== 'undefined') {
            // Do something to trigger fail() in the client caller.
        }
        return response;
    }, function(resp) {
        // This satisfies point 1 above.
        return { errorMessage: "Server error." };
    });
}
```

How may I satisfy the second requirement? I'm using jquery 3.1.1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just throw an error from your `then` callback.  The caller will "catch" it in their fail callback (though I suggest you learn to use standard `then` and `catch` and stop using jquery-specific `done` and `fail`).

```
function initData() {
    var promise = $.getJSON(url);

    return promise.then(function(response) {
        if (typeof response !== 'undefined' && response !== null && typeof response.errorMessage !== 'undefined') {
            throw new Error("uh oh!");
        }
        return response;
    }, function(resp) {
        // This satisfies point 1 above.
        throw new Error("server error");
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please elaborate a bit on the recommended alternative?

Comment: Just stop using `done` and `fail` -- they are jQuery-specific and before jQuery updated their implementation to match the Promise spec.  Instead call `then` and `catch` which are the spec-compliant functions.  They mostly work the same so you could change your "client code" to from `.done(...).fail(...)` to `.then(...).catch(...)` and it would work (and also work with a standard Promise)

Comment: I was insisting because I'd found a solution before posting the question, by using deferred objects, but I already had the question written down and was curious about alternatives. I'd already tried using throw following a friend's suggestion, but to my despair it didn't work, because I was using jquery 1.11.3 in the beginning, which doesn't support this. 

Regarding your answer, the line `return { errorMessage: "Server error." };` doesn't work as expected when using then/catch. I believe `throw` is mandatory in that case.

Comment: gotcha.  I fixed that bit.  And yes, earlier version of jQuery deferred's (before jQuery 3.0) were not compliant with the Promise spec.  I did not qualify this answer since your question specifically stated jQuery 3.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

To fail the promise, simply `throw` the result instead of `return`ing it:

```
function initData() {
    return $.getJSON(url)e.then(function(response) {
        if (typeof response !== 'undefined' && response !== null && typeof response.errorMessage !== 'undefined') {
            throw { errorMessage: "Response error." };
        }
        return response;
    }, function(resp) {
        throw { errorMessage: "Server error." };
    });
}
```

(This works only as of jQuery 3. For earlier versions, see [Throwing an Error in jQuery's Deferred object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10843297/1048572))