# How can i handle Error in Ajax deferred

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can i handle Ajax deferred error

```
 function CallingApi() {
      return  $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:10948/Api/Home/GetEmployee123',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            type:'GET',
        })
    }
    function Errorfunction(xhr) {
        //alert(xhr.status);
    }
```

Here I'm calling Ajax `PromiseApi`  is working fine but if there is any error, how can I alert there is an Error

```
    var PromiseApi = CallingApi();
    var ErrorPromise = Errorfunction();
    PromiseApi.done(function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, value) {
            console.log(value.EmpName);
        })
    })
```

Comment: Did you ask Google? You just chain the method `.fail()`.... as in `PromiseApi.fail(function(xhr) {
    console.log('error', xhr);
  });`

Comment: Errorfunction does not return a function so you it should not have ()

Comment: Duplicate to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792878/jquery-ajax-error-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792878/jquery-ajax-error-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this

```
function CallingApi() {
      var promise = $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:10948/Api/Home/GetEmployee123',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            type:'GET',
        });
    promise.done(function(data){
        $.each(data, function (i, value) {
            console.log(value.EmpName);
        });
   });
    promise.fail(function(xhr, status, error){
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
    });
};
```

Comment: .fail is not executing

Comment: Okay.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843297/throwing-an-error-in-jquerys-deferred-object
Check this?

Comment: @masshOle ur url is working Good but i need this in btn click

Comment: `$('#id-of-button').on('click',function(){
    CallingApi();
});`

Comment: No problem! Good luck